# How do I use remove_action on an add_action that uses an array?

Tags: filters, actions

This is a messy question :)  I'm running into a conflict between plugins and need to disable one (WP Bakery) on the front end of certain pages.

I'm looking at multiple questions on how to disable a plugin per page, but James Jackson's answer seems to be the best and most updated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774424/wordpress-disable-plugin-on-specific-pages-posts (I don't want to use another plugin like Plugin Organizer to disable plugins).

It works by finding the actions used to load the plugin and then removes them with `remove_action`, i.e.

```
 `remove_action('wp_head', 'easy_fancybox_enqueue_styles');`
```

For my issue, the main file j`s_composer.php` of the WP Bakery plugin loads this file `include/classes/core/class-vc-manager.php` and these are the actions in that file:

```
private function __construct() {
        $dir = WPB_PLUGIN_DIR;
        $this->setPaths( array(
            'APP_ROOT' => $dir,
            'WP_ROOT' => preg_replace( '/$\//', '', ABSPATH ),
            'APP_DIR' => basename( plugin_basename( $dir ) ),
            'CONFIG_DIR' => $dir . '/config',
            'ASSETS_DIR' => $dir . '/assets',
            'ASSETS_DIR_NAME' => 'assets',
            'AUTOLOAD_DIR' => $dir . '/include/autoload',
            'CORE_DIR' => $dir . '/include/classes/core',
            'HELPERS_DIR' => $dir . '/include/helpers',
            'SHORTCODES_DIR' => $dir . '/include/classes/shortcodes',
            'SETTINGS_DIR' => $dir . '/include/classes/settings',
            'TEMPLATES_DIR' => $dir . '/include/templates',
            'EDITORS_DIR' => $dir . '/include/classes/editors',
            'PARAMS_DIR' => $dir . '/include/params',
            'UPDATERS_DIR' => $dir . '/include/classes/updaters',
            'VENDORS_DIR' => $dir . '/include/classes/vendors',
            'DEPRECATED_DIR' => $dir . '/include/classes/deprecated',
        ) );
        // Load API
        require_once $this->path( 'HELPERS_DIR', 'helpers_factory.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'HELPERS_DIR', 'helpers.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'DEPRECATED_DIR', 'interfaces.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'CORE_DIR', 'class-vc-sort.php' ); // used by wpb-map
        require_once $this->path( 'CORE_DIR', 'class-wpb-map.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'CORE_DIR', 'class-vc-shared-library.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'HELPERS_DIR', 'helpers_api.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'DEPRECATED_DIR', 'helpers_deprecated.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'PARAMS_DIR', 'params.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'AUTOLOAD_DIR', 'vc-shortcode-autoloader.php' );
        require_once $this->path( 'SHORTCODES_DIR', 'core/class-vc-shortcodes-manager.php' );
        // Add hooks
        add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(
            $this,
            'pluginsLoaded',
        ), 9 );
        add_action( 'init', array(
            $this,
            'init',
        ), 11 );
        $this->setPluginName( $this->path( 'APP_DIR', 'js_composer.php' ) );
        register_activation_hook( WPB_PLUGIN_FILE, array(
            $this,
            'activationHook',
        ) );
    }
```

The `add_action` calls are not specific and use arrays.

How can I use `remove_action` on `add_action( 'plugins_loaded'`?

Os is there a way to disable the entire private function `__construct`?

Is there a better way to try to disable this plugin on certain pages?